# Unmarshall XML to embedded struct in go

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have a flat XML structure, which I want to unmarshall in to a struct which has one part embedded.  Is this possible?   What is the syntax, or what custom method can I write?

In this example, I tag the nested struct with a guess: `xml:""`, which is skipped over by "encoding/xml".

```
type FloatHolder struct {
    Value float32    `xml:"value"`
}


type pv struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name  `xml:"series"`
    Test1 FloatHolder `xml:""`   // does not populate :-(
    Test2 FloatHolder `xml:"nested"` // populates
}
func main() {
    contents := `<series>
                   <nested>
                     <value>1234</value>
                   </nested>
                   <value>1234</value>
                 </series>`

    m := &pv{}

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(contents), &m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%f %f\n", m.Test1.Value, m.Test2.Value)
}
```

Output: "0.000000 1234.000000"

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/aEdDLFYqL5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After comment interaction.

Yes you can. Let's say

XML:

```
<series>
    <value>123456</value>
</series>
```

Struct definition:

```
type FloatHolder struct {
    Value float32 `xml:",chardata"`
}

type pv struct {
    XMLName xml.Name    `xml:"series"`
    Test2   FloatHolder `xml:"value"`
}
```

Go Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/9sWQaw0HlS

---

Actually it's not a nested field, as per your XML. It belongs to `series` element.

Update your struct to following:

```
type pv struct {
    XMLName xml.Name    `xml:"series"`
    Test1   float32     `xml:"value"`
    Test2   FloatHolder `xml:"nested"`
}
```

Go Playground Link: https://play.golang.org/p/-mWrUMJXxX

Comment: This is different than what I'm looking for.  I explicitly want to unmarshall a top-level `value` in to a nested struct, as opposed to a top-level float32.

Comment: Accessing nested value into top-level is possible via `nested>value`, let me check pushing value into nested object is possible or not.

Comment: That's really great!  Is it possible also to have the "Holder" struct have multiple values, or would each value need to be wrapped in its own holder?

Comment: Each XML element needs field or struct holder to map the value. Multi values is not feasible. However if you have an `attribute` on XML element, you can map it to same holder.